# How to do VR rendering direct in opengl es android?

Tags: opengl-es, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I was wondering if there is some way to do Virtual Reality side-by-side rendering( as in google cardboard) directly with opengl es.

Comment: Did you figured something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use OpenGL ES and render 2 view ports with different camera. Each camera can be a bit apart from each other and have some small difference in angle.

Comment: That's okey, but how do i render it, specially on opengl implementation in android?